# Re-writing View Comment link to display node title

Tags: views, comments

I'm trying to re-write the [view_comment] field in a Comments View with the [title]. I have the [title] excluded and I'm re-writing [view_comment] with [title].

What I'm hoping is to show the node title in the view and it will link to the latest comment on the node. I think I need to 'output the [view_comment] field as a link' possibly with node/???? (or similar) as the absolute link.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 7 you can take advantage of core's new API to create permalinks to comments.

From the [patch on d.o](https://drupal.org/node/26966#comment-1720306)

> Since comments are paged there is no way to guarantee which page a
>   comment appears on. Comment paging and threading settings may be
>   changed at any time. With threaded comments, an individual comment may
>   move between pages as comments can be added either before or after it
>   in the overall discussion. Therefore we use a central routing function
>   for comment links, which calculates the page number based on current
>   comment settings and returns the full comment view with the pager set
>   dynamically.

In drupal 7, this routing function is

```
comment/%comment
```

So it would be best in your view (with comment as a base table) to pull out:

- cid (display none)
- title (node relationship, required)

Display title as a link, path it to

```
comment/[cid]
```

---

If you are using Drupal 6, I would suggest rolling with contrib to fix core - with https://drupal.org/project/permalink which backports the above functionality

Answer (score 0):

add the relationship "last comment" and don't select "relationship required" (otherwise it will only show nodes with comments.

Then add the "node id" and "comment id" fields above the title field and exclude them from display.
Edit your title and under "rewrite results" check "Output this field as a link" and enter "node/[nid]#comment-[cid]" for the link path.

Now your title links to the last comment for every node and if there is no comment it will just link to the node ("#comment-" won't have any effect).

Answer (score 0):

Note : a common issue, and annoying one, is that comment field options in Views 3 (7.x-3.11; and Views 2 also I believe) are not offered all the time.  So MotoTribe is quite right that you need to add a relationship to make them appear (not obvious; should be simpler imo).

**I'd like to add to the trick MotoTribe describes** :

If you use the Rewrite Output from Views, but from inside the Comment Count field, you can then specify to **Hide if empty**.  Therefore, if there are zero comments, none of the rewritten output proposed by MotoTribe will show up for nothing.  It makes for a cleaner tracker table.

Also, if you use the Comment Title field instead, you can get a direct link to the comment. In this case, by default, it will appear only if there is a comment.